# Create faceted xy scatters using vectors of column names in R

Tags: r, loops, scatter-plot

I have two character vectors of equal length; where position one in vector.x matches position one in vector.y and so on. The elements refer to column names in a data frame (wide format). I would like to somehow loop through these vectors to produce xy scatter graphs for each pair in the vector, preferably in a faceted plot. Here is a (hopefully) reproducible example. To be clear, with this example, I would end up with 10 scatter graphs.

```
vector.x <- c("Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Bathycoccus", "Brockmanniella", "Brockmanniella",  "Caecitellus_paraparvulus", "Caecitellus_paraparvulus")

vector.y <- c("Aliiroseovarius", "Neptuniibacter", "Pseudofulvibacter", "Thalassobius", "unclassified_Porticoccus", "Tenacibaculum", "Pseudomonas", "unclassified_GpIIa", "Marinobacter", "Thalassobius")
```

```
structure(list(Aliiroseovarius = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00487132352941176, 
0.0108639420589757), Marinobacter = c(0, 0.00219023779724656, 
0, 0.00137867647058824, 0.00310398344542162), Neptuniibacter = c(0.00945829750644884, 
0.00959532749269921, 0.0171310629514964, 0.2796875, 0.345835488877393
), Pseudofulvibacter = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00284926470588235, 0.00362131401965856
), Pseudomonas = c(0.00466773123694878, 0.00782227784730914, 
0.0282765737874097, 0.00707720588235294, 0.00400931195033627), 
    Tenacibaculum = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00505514705882353, 0.00362131401965856
    ), Thalassobius = c(0, 0.00166875260742595, 0, 0.0633272058823529, 
    0.147697878944646), unclassified_GpIIa = c(0, 0.000730079265748853, 
    0, 0.003125, 0.00103466114847387), unclassified_Porticoccus = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.00119485294117647, 0.00569063631660631), Aplanochytrium = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.000700770847932726, 0.0315839846865529), Bathycoccus = c(0.000388802488335925, 
    0, 0, 0.0227750525578136, 0.00526399744775881), Brockmanniella = c(0, 
    0.00383141762452107, 0, 0.000875963559915907, 0), Caecitellus_paraparvulus = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.000875963559915907, 0.00797575370872547)), row.names = c("B11", 
"B13", "B22", "DI5", "FF6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't explicit in my question and although the initial answers work perfectly for my subset data I actually have 100's of these to plot, do you have the piece of code that would allow me to plot multiple 4x3 grids on different pages? until it reaches the end of the vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rui Barradas shows, it's possible to get a very nice plot from **ggplot** and **gridExta**. If you wanted to stick to base R, here's how you'd do that (assuming your data set is called `df1`):

```
# set plot sizes
par(mfcol = c(floor(sqrt(length(vector.x))), ceiling(sqrt(length(vector.x)))))

# loop through plots
for (i in 1:length(vector.x)) {
  plot(df1[[vector.x[i]]], df1[[vector.y[i]]], xlab = vector.x[i], ylab = vector.y[i])
}

# reset plot size
par(mfcol = c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I can't up vote yet (sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long and convoluted but it works.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

df_list <- apply(data.frame(vector.x, vector.y), 1, function(x){
  DF <- df1[which(names(df1) %in% x)]
  i <- which(names(DF) %in% vector.x)
  if(i == 2) DF[2:1] else DF
})


gg_list <- lapply(df_list, function(DF){
  ggplot(DF, aes(x = get(names(DF)[1]), y = get(names(DF)[2]))) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab(label = names(DF)[1]) +
    ylab(label = names(DF)[2])
})


g <- do.call(grid.arrange, gg_list)
g
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I actually have 100's of these to plot, do you have the piece of code that would allow me to plot multiple 4x3 grids? until it reaches the end of the vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Not too elegant, but should get you going:

```
vector.x <- c("Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Aplanochytrium", "Bathycoccus", "Brockmanniella", "Brockmanniella",  "Caecitellus_paraparvulus", "Caecitellus_paraparvulus")
vector.y <- c("Aliiroseovarius", "Neptuniibacter", "Pseudofulvibacter", "Thalassobius", "unclassified_Porticoccus", "Tenacibaculum", "Pseudomonas", "unclassified_GpIIa", "Marinobacter", "Thalassobius")

df1 = structure(
  list(Aliiroseovarius = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00487132352941176, 0.0108639420589757),
       Marinobacter = c(0, 0.00219023779724656, 0, 0.00137867647058824, 0.00310398344542162),
       Neptuniibacter = c(0.00945829750644884, 0.00959532749269921, 0.0171310629514964, 0.2796875, 0.345835488877393),
       Pseudofulvibacter = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00284926470588235, 0.00362131401965856),
       Pseudomonas = c(0.00466773123694878, 0.00782227784730914, 0.0282765737874097, 0.00707720588235294, 0.00400931195033627),
       Tenacibaculum = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00505514705882353, 0.00362131401965856),
       Thalassobius = c(0, 0.00166875260742595, 0, 0.0633272058823529, 0.147697878944646),
       unclassified_GpIIa = c(0, 0.000730079265748853, 0, 0.003125, 0.00103466114847387),
       unclassified_Porticoccus = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00119485294117647, 0.00569063631660631),
       Aplanochytrium = c(0, 0, 0, 0.000700770847932726, 0.0315839846865529),
       Bathycoccus = c(0.000388802488335925, 0, 0, 0.0227750525578136, 0.00526399744775881),
       Brockmanniella = c(0, 0.00383141762452107, 0, 0.000875963559915907, 0),
       Caecitellus_paraparvulus = c(0, 0, 0, 0.000875963559915907, 0.00797575370872547)),
  row.names = c("B11", "B13", "B22", "DI5", "FF6"),
  class = "data.frame"
)

df2 = NULL
for(i in 1:10) {
  df.tmp = data.frame(
    plot = paste0(vector.x[i], ":", vector.y[i]),
    x = df1[[vector.x[i]]],
    y = df1[[vector.y[i]]]
  )
  if(is.null(df2)) df2=df.tmp else df2 = rbind(df2, df.tmp)
}

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(plot))
```